# ElasticSearch Query for range OR missing in array

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to create a query that will query the below mapping for values that have a "period" that either matches a specific date, or is missing it's value (with a null value). **Please note that I am working with a third-party database, so I cannot change the mappings**. Bear with me if the example data and mappings are large.. I've tried to cut everything nonessential away.

```
{
   "EXAMPLE":{
      "mappings":{
         "company":{
            "properties":{
               "CompanyData":{
                  "properties":{
                     "participantRelations":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "include_in_parent":true,
                        "properties":{
                           "participant":{
                              "type":"nested",
                              "include_in_parent":true,
                              "properties":{
                                 "unitNumber":{
                                    "type":"long"
                                 }
                              },
                              "organizations":{
                                 "properties":{
                                    "memberData":{
                                       "type":"nested",
                                       "include_in_parent":true,
                                       "properties":{
                                          "attributes":{
                                             "properties":{
                                                "values":{
                                                   "properties":{
                                                      "period":{
                                                         "properties":{
                                                            "validFrom":{
                                                               "type":"date",
                                                               "format":"dateOptionalTime"
                                                            },
                                                            "validTo":{
                                                               "type":"date",
                                                               "format":"dateOptionalTime"
                                                            }
                                                         }
                                                      }
                                                      "value":{
                                                         "type":"string"
                                                      }
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some example data. I've translated it from the (Danish) source it comes from, so any slight missspellings etc are just misstypes.

```
 { 
   "company": {
       "companyData":{
          "participantRelations":[
             {
                "participant":{
                   "unitNumber":4003857309
                },
                "organizations":[
                   {
                      "memberData":[
                         {
                            "attributtes":[
                               {
                                  "values":[
                                     {
                                        "value":"chairman",
                                        "period":{
                                           "validFrom":"2014-10-01",
                                           "validTo":"2016-08-11"
                                        }
                                     }
                                  ]
                               },
                               {
                                  "values":[
                                     {
                                        "value":"generalassembly",
                                        "period":{
                                           "validFrom":"2014-10-01",
                                           "validTo":"2016-08-11"
                                        }
                                     }
                                  ]
                               }
                            ]
                         }
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "memberData":[
                         {
                            "attributes":[
                               {
                                  "values":[
                                     {
                                        "value":"chairman",
                                        "period":{
                                           "validFrom":"2016-08-16",
                                           "validTo":"2017-06-08"
                                        }
                                     },
                                     {
                                        "value":"boardmember",
                                        "period":{
                                           "validFrom":"2017-06-09",
                                           "validTo":null
                                        }
                                     }
                                  ]
                               },
                               {
                                  "values":[
                                     {
                                        "value":"generalassembly",
                                        "period":{
                                           "validFrom":"2016-08-16",
                                           "validTo":"2017-06-08"
                                        }
                                     },
                                     {
                                        "value":"generalassembly",
                                        "period":{
                                           "validFrom":"2017-06-09",
                                           "validTo":null
                                        }
                                     }
                                  ]
                               }
                            ]
                         }
                      ]
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is something like the query below, which doesn't quite work as it has cases it cannot handle for reasons I do not know. What it needs to do is look for any company.participantRelations.organizations.memberData.attributes.values.period.validTo over a certain date, OR if the date is null. Now I know nulls are funky in ES, but I know that the date properties will always be there, but the validTo will be set to null if there is no date yet.

Furthermore, it needs to be nested on organizations as well, as I need a specific unitNumber to be present.

```
{
   "query":{
      "nested":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "nested":{
                        "filter":{
                           "bool":{
                              "must":[
                                 {
                                    "bool":{
                                       "should":[
                                          {
                                             "range":{
                                                "company.companyData.participantRelations.organizations.memberData.attributtes.values.period.validTo":{
                                                   "gte":"2017-08-14T15:23:11.011"
                                                }
                                             }
                                          },
                                          {
                                             "missing":{
                                                "field":"company.companyData.participantRelations.organizations.memberData.attributtes.values.period.validTo"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        },
                        "path":"company.companyData.participantRelations.organizations.memberData"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "company..companyData.participantRelations.participant.unitNumber":4003857309
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "path":"company.companyData.participantRelations"
      }
   }
}
```

This query works in two cases:

- Where there is only one entry in the list of values, and it's validTo date is null
- Where the validTo date is greater or equal to my date limit.

It does not seem to work if there are two entries, the first of which has a date that is earlier than my limit, and the second entry has a null value (as in the example).

I realize this is kind of convoluted, but with the database I'm querying that is just the way it is. I hope I've simplified it enough for you to get my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which ES version do you use?

Comment: Your mapping has several properties that are not nested(e.g. `CompanyData`).
Your query has incorrect paths in nested query (e.g. there is no `CompanyData` in the beginning)
Assuming that these issues are just typos, your query should get you your test document. Is it correct behavior?

Comment: The ES I'm calling is using 1.7.6.

The nested paths being incorrect was just a typo in the example. Sorry about that. The things I nest on are marked as nested, so it shouldn't cause problems that some others aren't, afaik?

Comment: Every field you use in nested query `path` should be nested. The ones that you don't use in nested query could be nested or not.

Comment: It still would be nice to see what you get and what you expect

Comment: Alright.  To make it as concrete as possible, here is the actual data that I know is in the database, but is not returned by my query:
DATA: https://pastebin.com/b1LjpRKB
QUERY: https://pastebin.com/s1VNksvg

I hope that helps your understanding, sorry that it's suddenly in Danish. Translating it is quite a task, that really should have been done by the database owners ;)

Comment: The issue is definitely related to the should: GTE or MISSING clause.

Comment: @bech do you have the source for the NEST query you are executing?